# union of two equivalence classes (Myhill–Nerode theorem)

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let a language, $L$ such that the equivalence relation, as defined in Myhill–Nerode theorem has $4$ equivalence classes; $A_1, \ldots, A_4$.

Let $S = A_1 \cup A_2$.

> 1. Is $S$ always regular?
> 2. How many equivalence classes does the relation $\sim S$ creates?

1. I think we may construct two DFA's, $D_1, D_2$ which accept $A_1, A_2$, respectively. Let $D$ to be the DFA accepting $L$. We construct $D_1$ by copying the states of $D$. We choose arbitrary $w\in A_1$ and run it on $D$. We mark as accepting state only the state which accepted the $w$. Same applied for $D_2$.
   Finally, we unite $D_1$ and $D_2$ be connecting a new starting state and two $\varepsilon$ arrows to each DFA. So we constructed in that way an NFA and therefore $S$ is a regular language. **Is this construction legal?**
2. My thought is $3$ because every word can be either at $S, A_3, A_4$. **Am I right?**

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Comment: Are you aware of the relation between the Myhill-Nerode classes and the minimal DFA?  How is the relation $\sim S$ defined? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: We haven't learned about minimal DFA I am afraid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... **Is this construction legal?**

The construction is legal, but it isn't guaranteed to recognize $S=A_1\cup A_2$. The problem is that $D_1$ and $D_2$ don't necessarily recognize $A_1$ and $A_2$. But they recognize them if $D$ is the minimal DFA recognizing $L$. But you are making your live unnecessary complicated anyway. You could just mark the states corresponding to $A_1$ and $A_2$ as the accepting states, and you have your DFA recognizing $S=A_1\cup A_2$.

> My thought is 3 because every word can be either at $S$, $A_3$, $A_4$. **Am I right?**

No, at least this argument is not convincing. The DFA constructed above still has 4 states, so we only know that it cannot be more than 4. We also know that it must be more than one, which leaves 2, 3, and 4 as possible answers. My own guess would be actually 4, but I assume here that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are just two arbitrary equivalence classes, i.e. that the indices have no significance.